# How to apply custom sort to column in AcitveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a Movie model with a name and release_date attribute, and the following ActiveAdmin code

```
ActiveAdmin.register Promotion do

  index do
    actions
    column :name
    column :release_date, sortable: :release_date
  end

end
```

When I sort by release_date desc, entries with no date bubble to the top. I would prefer if those entries are always at the bottom, regardless of the sort order. Is there any way to specify the compare function when sorting a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to redefine your problem.

It will be hard to achieve what you require with ActiveAdmin. Because ActiveAdmin's [order clause](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/order_clause.rb#L6) is very restrictive:

```
clause =~ /^([\w\_\.]+)(->'\w+')?_(desc|asc)$/
```

So you need to redefine `ActiveAdmin::OrderClause` class to accept `NULL LAST` or whatever is supported in your database system, or just accept the way ActiveAdmin works.

Answer (score 4):

I think that having to add an explicit column with a count cache to solve this is far overkill for what is needed. Why not just update `#scoped_collection` query in the controller to select an extra column? If it's in scope (e.g. for the current query), you can access it via the DSL.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foo do 
  index do
    column :things_count, sortable: :things_count
  end

  controller do 
    def scoped_collection
      super.select('foo.*, COUNT(things.id) as things_count').group('foo.id')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is definitely a more-viable answer than what was accepted.  @Nate